# What is the remainder when $x^{32}+71x-62$ is divided by $15x^{2}-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**question**

What is the remainder when $x^{32}+71x-62$ is divided by $15x^{2}-1$?

**My thoughts:**

I know that if it was to be divided by something like $3x^2-x$, the remainder would be 1 power less than the divisor. But in this scenario we have a gap between the powers, to clarify, it is $15x^2$ vs -1 and one has a power of two while the other has a power of 0 on the variable $x$.

thus I do not know how to apply the remainder theorem on this problem and would request help

My question is that are you able to set the remainder to be (ax+b)?

Comment: Assuming you mean as polynomials over the rational numbers?

Comment: Remainder theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{32}+71x-62=(15x^2-1)q(x)+ax+b$$

Now make $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$ and find $a$ and $b$, and the remainder will be:

$$r(x)=ax+b$$

Comment: My question is that are you able to set the remainder to be (ax+b)

Comment: Hi @JohnRawls, in fact we are! You already know that remainder must have a degree less than $2$ and then we can write it as $ax+b$. If that is not the case, after solve the problem like I did, you will naturally find $a=0$ if that is the case. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2\equiv \frac{-1}{15}\pmod{15x^2-1}$, you have that:

$$x^{32}\equiv \left(\frac{-1}{15}\right)^{16}=\frac{1}{15^{16}}\pmod{15x^2-1}$$

So:

$$x^{32}+71x-62\equiv 71x-\left(62-\frac{1}{15^{16}}\right)\pmod{15x^2-1}$$

Comment: How did $15^{-16}$ turn into $15^{-8}$?

Comment: Fixed. Stupid error.